# BinarySearch on javascript

Tags: javascript, binary, binary-search-tree, binary-search

alright then, given an ordered array, find the index of a specific element passed as parameter using the method known as binary search. In the event that the searched number is not found in the array return -1.

Example:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
binarySearch (array, 2) -> Would return 1 since array [1] = 2
[Where 2 would be the number on which we want to know its position in the array]
```

i have tryed this

```
var binarySearch = function (array, target) {
  var start = 0;
  var end = array.length-1
  while (start <= end) {
    let mid=Math.floor((start + end)/2);
    if (array[mid]===target) {
      return true;
    } else if (array[mid] < target) {
      start = mid + 1;
    } else {
      end = mid - 1;
    }
  }
  return array;

}
```

but not working am doing something wrong ?

```
AssertionError: expected true to equal 4

      160 | });
      161 | it ('Should return 4 for array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] if bu
sca 5 ', function () {
    > 162 | expect (binarySearch ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 5)). to.equal (4);
      163 | });
      164 |
      165 | it ('It should return -1 if it can't find the value searched in the array', fun
ction () {
```

Comment: The task expects you to return a number that is the index of the element (4 in this case). But you are returning `true`. Try returning `mid` instead. Also when you didn't find it, you return `array`, but the task asks you to return `-1`...

Answer (score 1):

You should return an index or -1, not `true` or `array`. See the demo:

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

var binarySearch = function (array, target) {
  var start = 0;
  var end = array.length-1
  while (start <= end) {
    let mid=Math.floor((start + end)/2);
    if (array[mid]===target) {
      return mid;
    } else if (array[mid] < target) {
      start = mid + 1;
    } else {
      end = mid - 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

console.log(binarySearch(array, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write it like this:

```
function binarySearch(list: number[], item: number) {
    let low = 0;
    let high = list.length - 1;

    while (low <= high) {
        let mid = Math.ceil(low + high / 2);
        let guess = list[mid]
        if(guess > item) high = mid - 1
        if(guess < item) low = mid + 1
        else return mid

    }
    return null
}
```